# using if -else in haskell to take decision based on Int value

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I have something like this

```
var1::Int
var1 = 1;
if var1
    then // call some fumction
    else // call some other function
```

What is the way to do this in Haskell? What I am doing is calling different functions depending on the value of variable `var` (note that it is an `Int`). `var1` can only take `1` or `0` as values. Note that I cannot use bool for my conditions.

Comment: Do you return the result of the function calls?

Comment: yeah , I will set the function return types accordingly. I am using this code as a part of some function.

Comment: `if` in Haskell can only use the Boolean conditions: `if (var1 == 1) then ... else ...` or `if (var1 == 0) then ... else ...`. `==` is testing the equality and returns a Boolean value, either `True` or `False`.

Comment: Any alternate to if statement for my case, which may be a better approach  ?

Comment: Haskell doesn't really have function calls

Comment: @immibis, yeah *functional* languages typically don't have those  (sarcasm).   Maybe you meant "procedure"?

Comment: @luqui In Haskell functions are "applied". They don't get called and they don't return. Calls and returns are kinds of control flow which do not exist in Haskell.

Comment: @immibis oh .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use pattern matching:

```
case var of
    0         -> callF
    1         -> callOtherF
    otherwise -> handleNot0or1
```

You can even create your own checker:

```
validate :: Int -> Bool
validate 0  = False
validate 1  = True
validate _  = whatever_you_decide
```

Comment: What if I am expecting a string, instead of 0,1 : That is either "" or "Some String" .Will `case var of
    ""         -> callF
    _         -> callOtherF` this work ?

Comment: @crystal it will, just change the type signature

Answer (score 1):

The type signature for `if` is `Bool -> a -> a -> a`. This means that you must give a boolean as the first argument. In other languages (like C or Python) an `if` statement tries to convert the argument given to it to a boolean. In Haskell, this fails because of the type system that doesn't let you reference a memory location as some other type.

To do your example you will have to use a (>)/(<) operators which can convert to instances of Ord a to a Bool.

Comment: or `==`, which deals with `Eq` .

Comment: Any alternate to if statement for my case, which may be a better approach ?

Comment: Pattern matching as Daniel Sanchez wrote or writing your own function that wrap around `if`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the return value, should suffice with pattern matching like this

```
boolSwitch 1 = 3+3
boolSwitch 0 = 3.0*2.5
boolSwitch _ = undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the if-else structure, you have to put it as a part of function definition, like so

```
function :: Int -> ...
function i =
    if i == 1
        then ...
        else ...
```

However, I don't see why you want to use `Int` instead of `Bool`. If `0` and `1` are the only integers you want to use, more 'haskellish' way of doing the thing you probably want to do is making a function with return type of `Maybe a`, in case of something else than `0` or `1` is given as an input, and using pattern matching:

```
function :: Int -> Maybe ...
function 0 = ... -- Has to return either 'Just ...' or 'Nothing'
function 1 = ... -- Same as above
function _ = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Since pattern matching has already been mentioned, I would like to mention guards:

```
myFunc a | (a == 0)  = fooCall
         | (a == 1)  = barCall
         | otherwise = etcCall
```

Of course there is always the simple if-then-else:

```
myFunc a = if (a == 0)
               then fooCall
               else if (a == 1)
                   then barCall
                   else etcCall
```